# What is the running time of this iterative function?

Tags: algorithm, performance

I'm having trouble analyzing the running time of the following iterative function, written in pseudocode:

```
procedure iterative_function(int n) {
    a = -42, b = 1;
    while (b < 5 * n) {
        int c = n * n * n;
        while (c > b) {
            a = 2 - a;
            c = c - b;
        }
        b = b + 5;

    }
}
```

I know the inner loop iterates at most floor((n^3-b)/b) + 1 times for each value of b in the outer loop, as (floor((n^3-b)/b)+1)b > n^3 - b so after floor((n^3 - b)/b)+1 iterations, z < y and the while loop terminates. Also, throughout the outer loop, 1 <= b < 5n and the inner loop iterates at least max{0, floor((n^3-b)/b) - 1} times, which is floor((n^3-b)/b)-1 for n sufficiently large. For n sufficiently large, we also have (n^3 - b)/2 b - 1 > 0. Also, b = 1 + 5(j-1) at the kth iteration, so the total number of iterations of the inner loop is at least sum_{j=0}^{n-1} frac{n^3 - (1+5j)}{2(1+5j)} - 1 and at most sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (floor(frac{n^3-(1+5j)}{1+5j}) + 1) <= sum_{j=0}^{n-1} frac{n^3}{1+5j}.
I'm not sure if it's in \Theta (n^4) or \Theta(n^3). Here, I'm using order notation, so if a function is in \Theta(n^3), it has approximately the same growth rate as the function f(n) = n^3.

[image]

Comment: Introduce a counter, t say, which you increment in the inner while loop. Then graph the function t(n). Should be clear then.

Comment: running it for say 5 different values of `n` is sufficient to distinguish between `n^3` and `n^4`.

Comment: Your last sum is similar to [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), where the nth harmonic number (1/1+1/2+...+1/n) is about ln(n). So the total running time should be Theta(n^3 * log(n)).

Comment: Why tag the C language when you stated you are programming in C++.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows function overloading and C doesn't.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: @user207421 thanks for the suggestion. So is it okay if I just typed sum_{j=0}^{n-1} n^3/(1+5j) <= n^4 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the upper bound being O(n^4) and the lower bound Ω(n^3), but the tight bound is actually neither one.

It's easy to see that the inner loop does about n^3/b iterations, where b takes the values 1, 6, 11, ..., 5n-4. So the total running time is n^3 * S_n, where S_n = 1/1 + 1/6 + 1/11 + ... + 1/(5n-4).

S_n looks very similar to the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) H_n = 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n.  It's known that H_n behaves asymptotically like ln(n) plus a small constant, so it's in ϴ(logn). We can show that S_n behaves similarly:

S_n = 1/1 + 1/6 + 1/11 + ... + 1/(5n-4) > 1/5 + 1/10 + 1/15 + ... + 1/5n = H_n / 5.

S_n = 1/1 + (1/6 + 1/11 + ... + 1/(5n-4)) < 1 + (1/5 + 1/10 + 1/15 + ... + 1/(5n-5)) = 1 + H_(n-1) / 5.

This shows that S_n is sandwiched between H_n / 5 and 1 + H_(n-1) / 5 which are both in ϴ(logn), making it ϴ(logn) itself. And this makes the total running time ϴ(n^3 * logn).

Answer (score 1):

You need to go in steps. You start with :

```
void iterative_function(int n) 
{
    int a = -42, b = 1;
    while (b < 5 * n) {
        int c = n * n * n;
        while (c > b) {
            a = 2 - a;
            c = c - b;
        }
        b = b + 5;
    }
}
```

`a` doesn't change anything to the behaviour of the code and the assignment is just one extra line, where another operation would be done. Let's remove it.

```
void iterative_function(int n) 
{
    int b = 1;
    while (b < 5 * n) {
        int c = n * n * n;
        while (c > b) {
            c = c - b;
        }
        b = b + 5;
    }
}
```

Let's change the inner loop for a `for`, that while make it easier to parse

```
void iterative_function(int n) 
{
    int b = 1;
    while (b < 5 * n) {
        int c = n * n * n;
        for(int i = 0; i < c/b; i++); // not exact but close enough for complexity
        b = b + 5;
    }
}
```

At this point you can see that the `while` is done `n` times. The `for` is done between *n^3* times and 1 times.

So, for big-O notation, you get *O(n^4)*. If you want the exact number of steps, you need to computed the exact product and fix the approximation above.

Edit: This gave an upper bound. This comment allows you to go further:

*Your last sum is similar to harmonic numbers, where the nth harmonic number (1/1+1/2+...+1/n) is about ln(n). So the total running time should be Theta(n^3 * log(n)). – interjay*